# Attempt to bundle typescript to a single file creates mystifying junk

Tags: typescript, webpack, bundle, tree-shaking, ts-loader

I am attempting to bundle the `emitPrefixes` Typescript source shown below into a single pure javascript file through webpack but failing dismally.

The resulting javascript code will be evaluated in a context I don't control, in which the emit() function is already defined (within the JS-based map reduce functionality of CouchBase, CouchDB, Cloudant etc). The resulting source must evaluate to a function.

The same source successfully transpiles to pure javascript using [typescript transpile](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/typescript.d.ts#L6271). However, I need webpack to do the transpilation in order to bundle any imported modules into a single javascript file (transpile leaves requires intact, but I believe webpack can inline them).

However, I can't get webpack to successfully transpile even this basic function source file (which only imports types and no code). My suspicion: having no references to the `emitPrefixes` function means webpack is optimising/treeshaking the function out of existence.

Does anyone know which webpack settings I need to be looking at to prevent it from optimising the build process and hence removing all my code. I have tried many combinations with no joy.

Here's the source I'm transpiling. In this case it has no imported values (only Types which are erased).

```
import type { EmitFunction } from "../../../../../lib/mapreduce";
import type { Word } from "../../types";

declare var emit: EmitFunction<string>;

function emitPrefixes(doc: Word) {
  if (doc?.type === "word") {
    emit(doc.id);
  }
}

emitPrefixes;
```

After adding the necessary rule to use `ts-loader`, webpack reported a successful compilation of the prefix.ts file. However, it outputs meaningless junk to the prefix.js file with none of the actual code in it. The example below shows some module metadata spat out by the compilation. With `"module": "es2015"` in tsconfig.json even this module metadata is missing and hence webpack generates an empty file.

```
(() => {
  "use strict";
  var r = { 568: (r, t) => {} },
    t = {};
  !(function e(s) {
    if (t[s]) return t[s].exports;
    var o = (t[s] = { exports: {} });
    return r[s](o, o.exports, e), o.exports;
  })(568);
})();
```

By contrast the typescript transpile procedure outputs this, which evaluates correctly to a function, and which is pretty much exactly what I want (apart from the __esModule fragment)...

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
function emitPrefixes(doc) {
    if ((doc === null || doc === void 0 ? void 0 : doc.type) === "word") {
        emit(doc.id);
    }
}
emitPrefixes;
```

The webpack procedure I am using to compile the source is below. Can anyone see which webpack configuration options might need to be set to stop it optimising all my code into non-existence because the function isn't referenced?

```
import path from "path";
import webpack from "webpack";

function promiseBundledSource(sourcePath: string): Promise<void> {
  const entry = `./${path.basename(sourcePath)}`; //webpack needs explicit relative path
  const context = path.dirname(sourcePath);
  const config = {
    entry,
    context,
    output: {
      path: context,
      filename: entry.replace(/\.ts$/, ".js"),
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, use: "ts-loader" },
        {
          test: () => true,
          sideEffects: true,
        },
      ],
    },
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    webpack(config, (err, stats) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else if (stats?.hasErrors()) {
        reject(stats.compilation.errors);
      }
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

async function run() {
  try {
    await promiseBundledSource(path.resolve(
      "./test/lib/testdomain/index/map/prefix.ts"
    ));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

run();
```

The tsconfig.json which webpack auto-detects looks like...

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

The following reference typescript transpile operation successfully generates the right code, but leaves imported modules as requires, without inlining them, which is why I need to get webpack to handle it instead...

```
import fs from "fs";
import {
  transpile,
  ScriptTarget,
  ModuleKind,
  ModuleResolutionKind,
} from "typescript";

const sourcePath = "./test/lib/testdomain/index/map/prefix.ts";

const jsSource = transpile(fs.readFileSync(sourcePath).toString(), {
  target: ScriptTarget.ES5,
  module: ModuleKind.None,
  moduleResolution: ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs,
  noImplicitUseStrict: true,
  esModuleInterop: false,
  strict: false,
});

console.log(jsSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the config object accepts an [optimisation configuration](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/types.d.ts#L1787). Adding the following property to the configuration object passed to webpack caused readable source code from the original function to make it through to the output

It arrived with lot of webpack boilerplate I'm now trying to work out how to remove, but it's there!

```
    optimization: {
      minimize: false,
      usedExports: false,
    },
```

Comment: Finally I used rollup which just worked more or less instantly (with the treeshake:false option) and didn't introduce lots of unnecessary webpack IIFE module cruft.